# Keyboard layout hung up

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have a problem with the keyboard layout. I use Ubuntu 12.04. I configured the layout so that I could interchange between a Norwegian and Hebrew keyboard. The system language of my Ubuntu is Norwegian and both my user name and password are written in latin characters. I had been typing Hebrew for some while, then I left the computer for a break. When I came back, I had to unlock the account but then the keyboard layout was locked in a Hebrew keyboard layout and I could not switch back to Norwegian. I tried to reboot the machine and to turn it off and on but not matter what I did I could only type Hebrew letters. So it was impossible for me to login with my own account which had a password written with latin characters. Finally I gave up and installed Ubuntu from scratch. Now I would like to be able to change between Hebrew and Norwegian keyboard layouts but I don't dare to do it before I know what went wrong.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If you can only see the small box with a password field, you should click "Switch user". This will give you the fancy login screen with the nice graphics. This one has some buttons in the top right, which should allow you to switch keyboard layout, as well as activate the on screen keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried switching the keyboard layout by using the button you mention and I tried the onscreen keyboard but I was only able to type Hebrew letters either if I chose Norwegian or Hebrew.

Comment: If you press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get a text terminal, do you still get the Hebrew letters? If this doesn't work, you might want to try holding shift while booting and then selecting recovery mode. I'm not sure, but it could make a difference.

Comment: I tried using a text terminal but got Hebrew letters there too. I will try holding shift while booting to get recovery mode. That sounds like a good advice.